# Why is PATH wrong with cron entry?

Tags: bash, cron

I have an entry in cron.d:

```
31 17 * * * root /home/some_user/.bash_profile; /home/some_user/bin/some_script
```

The profile sets a specific path, and I echo the current path in the profile to ensure its correct.
But, when the script executes, a command in it fails because it's not in PATH and, when I display the current PATH within the script - it's not what was set in the profile.

Why doesn't the PATH set in the profile survive into the script's execution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to set the desired environment variables you need to source the `.bash_profile` file with `. /home/some_user/.bash_profile`. In your case, you are executing the bash_profile file, which will basically execute that file and exit the shell. The next time some_script is run it will start with fresh environment variables. Check this link - [sourcing vs executing](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip)

The other option is to set the `PATH` environment variable at the top of the crontab file. That way it will be visible to the rest of the scripts.